# React flow: custom group node example

Tags: reactjs, react-flow

I'm studying the React Flow library documentation and trying to figure out if there is a way to create my own node that will be a group (I want to implement custom title with styles for node before children nodes). I didn't find anything in the documentation - neither in the *Docs/Sub flow* section, nor in the *Api/Custom nodes*.

As a temporary solution for implementing the node title, I created a special node for it and placed it as the first child. But I don't really like this solution.

P.S. Found the same question on library's gitlab repository discussion section, for now without answer - https://github.com/wbkd/react-flow/discussions/2592

P.P.S: On githab answered that any node becomes a parent if its child is given the parentNode parameter. Haven't checked yet.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed: any node can become a group if you specify its id to its children as *parentNode*

Answer (score 0):

> Every node can act as a parent. When another uses the id for parentNode, it gets a patent.

the author @moklick  said.